# Slash commands on nextcord

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

I wanted to add slash commands but unsuccessfully. After hours of documentation reading, examples checking I finally left the idea to try it on my current code. So I've litterally try the example code from the nextcord documentation. I copy/paste the code add the token and the guild ID. But that wasn't more successful.
My bot have admin permission (8 on the scope), intents are all check on the bot dev pannel and after hours of waiting... Nothing on the slash list. I thought that was a refresh problem on my discord client, so I tested run discord on several devices (pc, mac, phone, ...) but nope.

As I said I tried the example code with only the server id changed (and also the token correctely edited, the bot himself is running well)

```
import nextcord

client = nextcord.Client()
server = numberfromguildid


@client.slash_command(guild_ids=[server])  # limits guilds with this command.
async def ping(
    interaction: nextcord.Interaction,
):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Pong!")


client.run("TOKEN")
```

If anyone have a solution that would be life saver !

Comment: do you mean that you want this? client = nextcord.Client(command_prefix='/')

Comment: "do you mean that you want this? client = nextcord.Client(command_prefix='/') – 
ShadowGunn"

Nope the question wasn't about that. As I said the objective was to had Slash commands not change the prefix.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you enable `applications command` while generating OAuth2 link? and you still need to import modules from `nextcord` and `nextcord.abc`, Your code should look like this:

```
from nextcord import Interaction, SlashOption, ChannelType
from nextcord.abc import GuildChannel
from nextcord.ext import commands
import nextcord
```

The way you initiate the client seems to be wrong also I guess

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='YOUR_PREFIX')
```

Comment: Hey thank's for the answer ! My mistake was the OAuth2.
The imports were non essentials.

by importing nextcord if you call the function by using : nextcord.something you will have the thing. So in this example we just create an interaction with a simple answer. There is no need of abc or ext and also the only one used here from nextcord import was Interaction but I call it here : interaction: nextcord.Interaction

Comment: `commands.Bot` and `nextcord.Client` are two different apps, and `Client` suffices for OP's use. Also, you don't need to import `GuildChannel`, `commands`, `SlashOption` or `ChannelType` for OP's example, this is misleading.

Comment: Yep my bad I should have read the docs.